# How to get parameter types using method name in java?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, parameters

Say, I have a class.

```
class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Like this, I have more than one data transfer classes. And I want to have a class where it will take method `name` (`String.class`) and parameter `value` (`Object.class`) dynamically as shown in the below snippet.

```
class Mapper{
    private Person person = new Person();
    private Method method = null;
    public void map(String methodName, Object parameterValue){
         // 1. Get the method using methodName.
         // 2. Get the method's parameter type.
         // 3. Type cast 'parameterValue' to parameter type.
         // 4. Call the method on 'person' object by passing type cast value
         //    from the 3-step(above).
    }
}
```

I have tried searching on it. I got the results on Reflection API as shown in the snippet below.

```
Class<String> clz = String.class;
for (Method m : clz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
   System.err.println(m.getName());
   int paramCount = m.getParameterTypes().length;
   for (int i = 0;  i < paramCount;  i++) {
      System.err.println("  arg" + i);
   }
}
```

But, this kind of approach doesn't meet my need. Hope you understand.

Comment: The Reflection API would be the way to go. This seems like a shady design, though. What, again, is the purpose of `map`?

Comment: Why doesn't it meet your needs?

Comment: you want to invoke a method dynamically on which class?

Comment: Thanks all. I got that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use reflection, I don't think there is any way to call a method dynamically in Java.
And while you are using Reflection API, look at the following method from class Method.

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

It is clear that you won't be needing to cast the arguments passed to this method.

Comment: This way, the caller would have to cast the return.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Person {
    public static final Map<String, BiConsumer<Person, ?>> methodMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        methodMap.put("setId", (BiConsumer<Person, Integer>) Person::setId);
        methodMap.put("setName", (BiConsumer<Person, String>) Person::setName);
    }

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public <T> void map(String methodName, T parameterValue){
     ((BiConsumer<Person, ? super T>) Person.methodMap.get(methodName))
         .accept(person, parameterValue);
}
```

I'm assuming you only want to use this with your set methods, since you always want to pass an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line if you go via json, for example using jackson:

```
private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // it's threadsafe
```

Then in your code:

```
Person person = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(map), Person.class);
```

You could similarly use Gson or another json library of your choice.

---

Some test code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", 3);
map.put("name", "bob");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Person person = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(map), Person.class);

System.out.println(person.getId());      
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

Output:

```
3
bob
```

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian . I got it.